# Bash script that checks website every 10 seconds

Tags: bash, web

The following script checks a sites content to see if any change has been done to it, every 10 seconds. It's for a very time sensitive application. If something on the site has changed, I merely have seconds to `do` something else. It will then start a new download and compare cycle and wait for the next change and `do` cycle. The `do` something else, has yet to be scripted and not relevant to the question.

The question: Will it be a problem for a public website to have a script downloading a single page *every* 10-15 seconds. If so, is there any other way to monitor a site, unmanned?

```
#!/bin/bash
Domain="example.com"
Ocontent=$(curl -L "$Domain")
Ncontent="$Ocontent"

until [  "$Ocontent" != "$Ncontent" ]; do
Ocontent=$(curl -L "$Domain")

#CONTENT CHANGED TRUE
#if [ "$Ocontent" == "$Ncontent ]; then
#  Ocontent=$(curl -L "$Domain")
#fi

echo "$Ocontent"
sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you're going to run into:

- If the site notices and has a problem with it, you may end up on a banned IP list. Using an IP pool or other distributed resource can mitigate this.
- Pinging a website *precisely* every x number of seconds is unlikely. Network latency is likely to cause a great deal of variance in this.
- If you get a network partition, your code should know how to cope. (What if your connection goes down? What should happen?)
- Note that getting the immediate response is only part of downloading a webpage. There may be changes to referenced files, such as css, javascript or images that are not immediately apparent from just the original http response.

Comment: "Using an IP pool"... tried to google this, came up nothing. Can you provide some links to info? Thanks.